# Bootstrap dropdown menu on hover (With Creative-Tim Icon Navbar)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

This is not the same as just a normal Bootstrap navbar, it is the Creative Tim icon navbar for Bootstrap found at (http://www.creative-tim.com/live/navbar-with-icons) I'm having some trouble getting my dropdown navbar to open when hovered over. I tried using...

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
```

but have had no joy. I suspect the creative tim navbar is getting in the way of something.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <nav class="navscroll navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #ecf1f0; color: #fff;" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="scroll">
        <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
            <p>Home</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true">
              </i>
              <p>About Us</p>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>

        <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true">
    </i><p>Products</p></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">

      <li class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown" style="font-size:17px;">
          <li><a href="#process" style="font-weight: bold">Banner Systems</a></li>
          <li><a href="#process">Roll Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#process">L/X Banner</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#process" style="font-weight: bold">Cases</a></li>
          <li><a href="#process">Foam Cases</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

        <li class="col-sm-4">
          <ul class="multi-column-dropdown" style="font-size:17px;">
            <li><a href="#process" style="font-weight: bold">Image Walls</a></li>
            <li><a href="#process">Pop Up wall</a></li>
            <li><a href="#process">Tube Wall</a></li>
            <li><a href="#process">Alu Wall</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-4">
          <ul class="multi-column-dropdown" style="font-size:17px;">
            <li><a href="#process" style="font-weight: bold">Outdoor Systems</a></li>
            <li><a href="#process">Outdoor / Flags</a></li>
            <li><a href="#process">Wall Frames</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>


    </ul>
</li>


      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
            <p>Shop</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
            <p>Downloads</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
            <p>News</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true">
          </i>
          <p>Contact Us</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>


 </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS for the Navbar dropdown menu

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9000;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -ms-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -o-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
    -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
}

.navbar-nav > li.open > .dropdown-menu{
    -webkit-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
    -o-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
    transform-origin: 29px -50px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -moz-filter: none;
    -ms-filter: none;
    -o-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the site creative tim give the li the class open with Javascript. But for you try this:

Change this:

```
.navbar-nav > li.open > .dropdown-menu{
   -webkit-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   -moz-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   -o-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   -ms-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   -o-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1;
   -ms-filter: none;
   -webkit-filter: none;
   -moz-filter: none;
   -ms-filter: none;
   -o-filter: none;
   filter: none;
}
```

to this:

```
.navbar-nav > li:hover> .dropdown-menu{
   -webkit-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   -moz-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   -o-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   -ms-transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   transform-origin: 29px -50px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   -o-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1;
   -ms-filter: none;
   -webkit-filter: none;
   -moz-filter: none;
   -ms-filter: none;
   -o-filter: none;
   filter: none;
}
```

Change li.open to li:hover

Comment: Perfect, although the original answer solved the problem, it didn't seem to translate when the menu was collapsed to the hamburger version. This solution works when responsive, thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is blocking it

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
padding: 0;
z-index: 9000;
position: absolute;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
opacity: 0;
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
-webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-moz-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-ms-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-o-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-transform: scale(0);
-moz-transform: scale(0);
-o-transform: scale(0);
-ms-transform: scale(0);
transform: scale(0);
-webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
-moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
-o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
-ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
}
```

All you have to do is change this:

```
.navbar-nav > .li.open > .dropdown-menu{
...
}
```

Into

```
.navbar-nav > .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu{
...
}
```

See the live example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgaVLv

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, this solved the problem :)